# Build Failure while executing in Jenkins due to custom dependencies for maven pom.xml

Tags: java, maven, selenium, jenkins, testng

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project XYZ: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.company.systemtest:xyzautomation:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT: Failure to find report.customreport.atu:firstartifact:jar:1.0 in https://repository-saucelabs.forge.cloudbees.com/release was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of saucelabs-repository has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException

This happened as i've added a report JAR file(by creating custom dependencies for maven). When i run the same program locally then i didn't faced any issues but in Jenkins i am getting the above exception

FYI : I've also set the Local Maven Repo in System configuration to "~/.m2/repository" (where i can literally see the custom jar)

Answer (score 0):

> "...resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of
>   saucelabs-repository has elapsed or updates are **forced**"

You could force updates of dependencies with **-U**:

```
mvn clean install -U
```

Comment: Downloading: https://repository-saucelabs.forge.cloudbees.com/release/report/customreport/atu/firstartifact/1.0/firstartifact-1.0.pom
         
       
[WARNING] The POM for report.customreport.atu:firstartifact:jar:1.0 is missing, no dependency information available
Downloading: https://repository-saucelabs.forge.cloudbees.com/release/report/customreport/atu/firstartifact/1.0/firstartifact-1.0.jar
         
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/report/customreport/atu/firstartifact/1.0/firstartifact-1.0.jar

Comment: Diyarbakir, I am not able download still now. I can see the jar file inside it and able to execute the same maven project by 'mvn test' . but what is the problem with jenkins

Answer (score 0):

> **report.customreport.atu:firstartifact:jar:1.0** in https://repository-saucelabs.forge.cloudbees.com/release was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of saucelabs-repository has elapsed or updates are forced

This says that your artifact is not found locally. This jar looks like something you have build but did not publish to your central repo.

You will have to either publish it and if it is published and is not downloaded as per the message you will have to force update with the -U flag.

Comment: I am not able to download still suresh. And with jenkins only i am facing the issue.